# FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag always returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have an `Activity` in which I switch the content by replacing a `Fragment`.
In the `onCreate` of this `Activity`, I set the first `Fragment` with this code:

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new FooFragment(), "f_0").commit();
```

After that, I want to switch this `Fragment` by another one depending on an `Integer` (I use a drawer), here is the code:

```
int position = //I get my index here
Fragment f = fm.findFragmentByTag("f_" + position); //(1)

if (f == null) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            f = new FooFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            f = new BarFragment();
            break;
        //Etc...
    }
}

//Then I replace the actual Fragment by the new one
fm.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, f, "f_" + position)
    .commit();
```

My problem is that the code on (1) always return null so every time I change the `Fragment`, it creates a new instance. I want to have at any time only one instance of each `Fragment` type.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set first fragment:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack("f_0").replace(R.id.container, new FooFragment(), "CURRENT_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();
```

---

Use this function to replace fragments:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("CURRENT_FRAGMENT_TAG");

    //to avoid adding the same fragment, you can use 'instanceof' instead of comparator
    if (currentFragment.getClass() == fragment.getClass()) {
        return;
    }
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(tag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(tag).replace(R.id.container, fragment, "CURRENT_FRAGMENT_TAG")
            .commit();

}
```

Example execution:

```
replaceFragment(new FooFragment(), "f_" + position);
```

---

Override `onBackPressed`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
        finish();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Got the same issue :/
I tested with a `static int` to count the number of instance of the `FooFragment` and it still increase every `Fragment`swap.

Comment: So if you really want one instance of fragment (`onCreate` will be called only once), you should then don't use mu solution, and in your fragments, in `onCreate` method add `setRetainInstance(true)`.